# nginx can't reverse proxy 302 internal from form post

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

my reverse configuration:

`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_redirect https://backend.xyz:2083/ /;
        proxy_pass https://backend.xyz:2083;
        sub_filter backend.xyz:2083 front.xyz;
        sub_filter_once off;
    }`

When running,it seems everything is ok. my site is based on drupal7. but when I post a login form.The login post is success for fonrt.xyz and not for backend, but the uri is redirect to https://backend.xyz:2083.
following some tips on web,I add some configuration for this location:

`proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 302 = @handle_page;`

then add new location:

`location @handle_page {
    rewrite ^/  $scheme://front.xyz/  last;
}`

now,the uri is right,but the login form post are both fail..so,How can I post it successfuly for front.xyz and make the 302 status to front.xyz ? add some change for front-nginx or backend-nginx ?

Comment: Remove the `proxy_redirect off;` statement, it seems to be in direct conflict with the other `proxy_redirect` directive.

Comment: Hi,when i comment this line and use http for backend site,it works.Thanks very much!  but why can't https..while the backend is https,comment this line make the front site down.